# Problem with ustate react native and animation

Tags: react-native, animation

I have a problem with my code. I understand if my initial state of toggled = false and  enter the condicional but the animation not run and the the weirdest thing is when I separeate in two function whit two different bottom the animation run but I want to run in one only function.
I need help with that.
Thank you.

```
const runTwoOption:any = () => {
        setToggled(!toggled);
        if(!toggled){
            Animated.parallel([
                runLoop(),
                Animated.timing(_scale, {
                    toValue: 1,
                    useNativeDriver: false,
                })
            ]).start();
        }else{
            Animated.parallel([
                Animated.timing(_scale, {
                    toValue: 0,
                    useNativeDriver: false,
                }),
                Animated.timing(_rotate,{
                    toValue:0,
                    useNativeDriver:false
                })
            ]).start();
        }
    }
```

these are the functions separated

```
const runAnimationsInParallel: any = () => {
        Animated.parallel([
            runLoop(),
            Animated.timing(_scale, {
                toValue: 1,
                useNativeDriver: false,
            })
        ]).start()
    }

    const stopAnimationsInParallel: any = () => {
        Animated.parallel([
            Animated.timing(_scale, {
                toValue: 0,
                useNativeDriver: false,
            }),
            Animated.timing(_rotate,{
                useNativeDriver:false,
                toValue:0,
            }),
        ]).start();
    }
```

That is my DOM, tha button with title null not working.

```
<View>
            <Animated.Image
                source={require('../assets/logo_baufest.jpg')}
                style={styleAnimationToImage}
            />
            <Button title="PLAY" onPress={runAnimationsInParallel} />
            <Button title="PAUSE" onPress={stopAnimationsInParallel} />
            <Button title="RUN" onPress={runTwoOption} />
        </View>
```

Answer (score 0):

I fif my problem, when I create my animation don't use useReft() I was a big problem. I read the consulting https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/25069.